# Just start using assembly (GAS), and has segmentation fault in this short code

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, gnu-assembler, att

I am learning AT&T x86 Assembly these days. I'm writing the code which multiplies two 32-bit integers without using "*". The problem is that the debugger keeps telling me that I have Segmentation Fault. Here is my code.

```
.global _start


.data

a:
    .long 0

b:
    .long 0

count:
    .long 0

.text

_start:

    movl $0, %eax
    movl $a, %ebx
    movl $b, %ecx
    movl $0, %edx

    for_mult:
        cmpl $32, count
        je end_for_mult

        carry_bit:
            shr $1, %ecx
            jnc is_zero

            addl (%ebx), %eax

            is_zero:
                shl $1, %ebx

        incl count
        jmp for_mult
    end_for_mult:

done:
    movl %eax, %eax
```

The debugger shows that segmentation fault appears at "addl (%ebx), %eax", and I can't figure out why. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should consider what `shl $1, %ebx` does to `ebx` and how that affects `addl (%ebx), %eax` in *the next* round of the loop.

Comment: When the debugger says segmentation fault, and points to some instruction, you can check the memory address used (value in `ebx` in this case). Then you can check against your allocated memory (usually `.data`/`.rodata` sections labels), if that points to a place where you want. Then you can start to search (probably by stepping through the code 1 instruction at time), why you went off the valid/expected memory. Btw, you have still some registers free, why not using one also for `count`? Actually why not use registers only, and store into memory just result? It's usually easier+faster.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing addresses and values.

Remove the $ signs to

```
movl a, %ebx
movl b, %ecx
```

(Your code actually moves the addresses of `a` and `b` to the registers and not the values!)

Remove the bracket around `%ebx`

```
addl %ebx, %eax
```

You want the value of ebx not the value ebx points to.